# setText() not working from another Activity's onClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, textview

I can't figure out why my code is not working:

**First Activity**

```
public static TextView name_contact;
public static TextView message_contact;
public static TextView count_contact;
public static TextView timestamp_contact;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.researchpurpose);

    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewConvlist);
    chatRoomsAdapter = new ChatRoomsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.chat_rooms_list_row);
    listView.setAdapter(chatRoomsAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3)
        {
            message_contact = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message);
        }
    });
}
```

**Second Activity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_acitivy);

    ImageButton buttonSend = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            FirstActivity.message_contact.setText("IL N'Y A QUE TOI");
        }
    });
}
```

Because if I put the code below in **Second Activity**, it works!

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_acitivy);

    FirstActivity.message_contact.setText("IL N'Y A QUE TOI");

}
```

And when checking the log, I do NOT get any error...

Comment: You have only found the View, not setting text.

message_contact = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message);

Comment: Where is the listView.setAdapter(...) ???

Comment: I haven't included it in this post but here's my full code : (edited version of the post)             And I'm setting the text in the Second Activity

Comment: inside a callback the reference has to be final

Comment: I can't set it to final since I need to modify it depending on the item

Comment: Would you please describe what you want to do? There maybe a better way to do it, Tell me what FirstActivity is for and what SecondActivity is for?

Comment: I need to display a list of contacts in the first activity (with the last message for each contact) and in the second activity I need to update this message in order to match the last received/sent one. Weird thing : the keyboard is always reseting the message to the initial one (for instance if i created the item with as message "hello" and then set it to "hi", displaying the virtual keyboard will reset the message value to "hello")

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out ! Turns out that the virtual keyboard is stopping the order when shown (when I say the order I mean `FirstActivity.message_contact.setText("IL N'Y A QUE TOI");`).

So I am closing/hiding the virtual keyboard before sending the order with this piece of code :

```
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

And after this, the text is being set properly.

But I have to say I don't understand why the code doesn't work when the keyboard is shown.